# Why is my JavaScript code returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
     //this gets the value from input field and stores in the tenNums array

      var tenNums = [];

      function myFunction() {
        var nums = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = nums;
        tenNums.push(nums);
      }

       // I want this function to sort the array and print the 3rd highest number

      function myDisplay() {
        tenNums.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a - b;
        });
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tenNums[tenNums.length - 3];
      }
```

```html
 <head>
    <title>Trial Questions</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>
      <u
        >Write a program that reads ten numbers and figures out which is the
        third highest</u
      >
    </h3>

    <h3>Enter any random ten numbers</h3>

    <input type="text" id="myNumber" /> <br />
    <br />

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>

    <p>You entered these numbers: <span id="display"></span></p>

    <p>Click on the button below to see third highest.</p>

    <button onclick="myDisplay()">Display</button>

    <p>The third highest number is <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

I am trying take user input from the user, print it out and place it in an array to sort it and print out which is the third highest. The input value from the user prints out alright but when 
I try to sort the array it prints out undefined. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Make sure your array has atleast 3 elements to find the third largest element

Comment: You’re only pushing a single element: a string. How should the string be entered?

Comment: first you can split all the numbers of form string to array index form by using` nums.split("")` and then you can apply sort method on it

Comment: @Zon _“array index form”_? _`nums.split("")`_? The OP wants to sort _numbers_, not single-digit array indexes or single-character strings.

Comment: @SebastianSimon what is the return value of document.getElementById("myNumber").value ? not single-character string?

Comment: @Zon It would definitely be a string, provided this `value` property is the original `HTMLInputElement.prototype.value` getter bound to the existing `<input>`. It _could_ be a single-character string. But the OP said nothing about the input format so far. That’s why I asked the OP _“How should the string be entered?”_ more than half an hour ago. Whether or not the input is a single character is unrelated to the question of why `.split("")` is chosen in the answers below; that method call results in an _array of single characters_. Even if `.map(Number)` is used, we get _single_-digit numbers.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I want the input format to be in numbers.

Comment: @OzeeInspire “In numbers”? You can’t input “numbers” in an `<input type="text">`, just a _single string_. “In numbers” is not a specific _format_, like “a comma-separated string of numbers” or “a string of tokens separated by a comma and a space” or “a JSON-encoded array of numbers”. What is the format of your string?

Comment: @SebastianSimon can you please help me rewrite the code so it actually works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
 //this gets the value from input field and stores in the tenNums array
  var tenNums = [];

  function myFunction() {
    var nums = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;    
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = nums;
    tenNums=nums.split('').map(Number); // this will return an array 
  }

   // I want this function to sort the array and print the 3rd highest number

  function myDisplay() {
    tenNums.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tenNums[tenNums.length - 3];
  }
</script>
```

Comment: _`// define string var`_ — Why? _`nums.split('')`_ — The OP wants to sort numbers, not single-character strings.

Comment: nums is a string, and to convert string into array index form we can use split()

Comment: And again, here: _“array index form”_? The OP wants to sort _numbers_, not single-digit array indexes (positive integers less than 10) or single-character strings.

Comment: @Zon your solution above didn't work for me. It still printed out undefined. I am a code newbie please help me out.

Comment: as @SebastianSimon said above, yeah, I want to sort numbers, not strings. Thanks y'all for your help so far, appreciated.

Comment: _“`.map(number)`”_ — you mean [`.map(Number)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). Spelling matters in JavaScript.

Comment: it worked, .map(Number) worked for me. Thanks  @SebastianSimon .

Comment: I just realized nums.split(" ") alone with out the .map(Number)  method also works.